# How to access Google calendar events in Unity3D?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, google-calendar-api, virtual-reality, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm building a [VR/AR calendar](https://youtu.be/RspvTs3cDQA) in Unity, and looking for the easiest way to read calendar event data from Google and Facebook (let's just start with Google).  I've tried using the [Google Calendar C# API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/dotnet), but Unity doesn't support .NET 4.0 or above (Google Calendar API only works with .NET 4.0 and above). Unity does have a .NET 4.6 Experimental version, but in Visual Studio after installing Google.Apis.Auth etc and other packages needed in PuTTY package manager the C# code would still not recognize the imported packages below:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
```

So next I tried a different approach: I tried installing the Unity Firebase plugin.  It only works for iOS and Android for now, so I started a new project just to start clean.  There are only a few YouTube videos about Firebase in Unity in general, and they don't get into Google Auth, just Google Analytics and regular plain email/password, so it's been trial and error for a few weeks now. I feel like [this guy](http://technicalartistry.blogspot.ca/2015/07/oauth2-unity-and-month-of-cursing.html), except I'm not working with a FitBit, and I don't have it figured out. Does anybody have insight on how to go about this?

More important question: If I were to get Google Auth working through Firebase in Unity, how would I go about pulling the Google Calendar event data associated with that account? Would that be back through the C# script?

Is there another way all together that I'm probably missing? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify your question. The Google Calendar API supports any language that can send HTTP POST and HTTP Gets.   The Google .net client library currently requires a min of .net 4.5 to run.   There is currently no support in the library for unity there is an issue [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/531) which states that we will probably not support it.

That being said you can still add google calendar to your project you will just have to code your own library for it.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get this working in a [javascript version](http://circaevum.com/3jsDemo.html) of the project (to avoid the whole .net client issue), but it's a lot slower than an exe built in Unity. Sounds like Unity is phasing out javascript though.

Would the Firebase Google Auth help at all, or would it be easier to do everything from the new library? I can create GameObjects in Unity to get the user's login info, and I was able to get an HTTP Get request to return geoJSON data in Unity, but idk how to pair the login credentials with the HTTP Get request.

Comment: sorry I can't help much with that I have never used Unity.

Comment: Okay, from a strictly code perspective then, is there a way to send login credentials along with an [HTTP Get request for Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/get) without importing those Google Auth libraries?

Comment: start here get authentication to work and everything else is a piece of cake https://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/

Comment: Thanks. I'll see if I can get a browser to pop up in Unity, and if so I'll report back

Comment: this does not work as there is no way to bring up a browser in Unity

Comment: Hey guys check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64570230/2416112. I created a DLL file to get google calendar events.

Comment: Thanks @SaadAnees, this is just what I was looking for!