# Google OAuth Access Token Empty

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

i think this question might be asked a Million Times but i did not find any answers out there.

I'm trying to access Google Calendar with my Unity Project, so I'm Using C# but cant use the Official google client libraries as its not supported.

Sadly Every time i try to get the Access Token from the server i get either a 404 or just a empty response.

## My Code:

```
private static string tokenUrl = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/";
public static string GetOAuthTokens(string auth_code, string grantType)
{
    RestClient rc = new RestClient(tokenUrl);
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.Parameters.Clear();

    request.Resource = "token";
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.AddParameter("auth_code", auth_code, ParameterType.RequestBody);
    request.AddParameter("client_id", client_id, ParameterType.RequestBody);
    request.AddParameter("secret", client_secret, ParameterType.RequestBody);
    request.AddParameter("grant_type", grantType, ParameterType.RequestBody);
    request.AddParameter("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:4444", ParameterType.RequestBody);
    return rc.Execute(request).Content;
}
```

And i've called that method with:

```
 Debug.Log(OAuth2.GetOAuthTokens(code, "authorization_code"));
```

that `Debug.Log` is just for debugging.

I've seen a lot of people saying i need to whitelist my Uri but i cant find that menu point in the credentials.

Im searching for about 6 hours now. Please Help!

Comment: Try this.  https://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/.

Comment: This is also a very simple example I made a number of years ago https://www.daimto.com/google-apis-auth-simple/   Let me know if you have any questions.    I have never worked with unity3d but i would love to help you work this out its should work.

Comment: @DalmTo How come your using a different endpoint as stated in the Official Docs?
Did they forget to update the docs or is your article based on a older version?

Comment: @DalmTo read your articles and tried it but my response is still empty + im getting response code 0 wich is strange

Comment: Endpoints have changed since I wrote that.   Use the one from the discovery doc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:
`request.AddParameter("auth_code", auth_code, ParameterType.RequestBody);`

had to be: `request.AddParameter("code", auth_code, ParameterType.GetOrPost);`

and i think i had to rename the Parameter keys to match the Documentation

Answer (score 2):

I made a DLL file of Google Calendar using their .NET SDK as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/dotnet).
I modified it a little to work with Unity and then used that dll file in Unity project. It worked for me.

**Below is DLL code:**

```
  static string[] Scopes = { CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly };
    static string ApplicationName = "Google Calendar API .NET Quickstart";

    public void Main()
    {
        UserCredential credential;
     
        using (var stream =
            new FileStream(UnityEngine.Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created
            // automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.
            string credPath = "token.json";
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
        }

        // Create Google Calendar API service.
        var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });

        // Define parameters of request.
        EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List("primary");
        request.TimeMin = DateTime.Now;
        request.ShowDeleted = false;
        request.SingleEvents = true;
        request.MaxResults = 10;
        request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;

        // List events.
        Events events = request.Execute();
        Debug.Log("Upcoming events:");
        if (events.Items != null && events.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var eventItem in events.Items)
            {
                string when = eventItem.Start.DateTime.ToString();
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(when))
                {
                    when = eventItem.Start.Date;
                }
                Debug.Log("Event Summery: " + eventItem.Summary + " | " + " On " + when);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("No upcoming events found.");
        }
        Console.Read();

    }
```

**On Unity Side Code:**

```
public Calendar calendar = new Calendar();

private void Start()
{
    calendar.Main();
}
```

It gives me calendar event summery and date. You can download project from [here](https://github.com/SaadAnees/UnityGoogleCalendar).

Comment: Appreciate your Help, gonna fall back to your Api once im giving up. But im trying to get mine working for educational purposes.

Comment: Using the SDK, do you see a way to be able to POST events to a Calander?

Comment: @i773 its an old sdk i made. it will just show the google calendar on browser. From browser you can definitely set events